# Show and edit escaped character in QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to show escaped characters like carriage return line feed "\r\n" characters in a QLineEdit in a human readable (escaped) way automatically?

Alternatively is there an easy method to automatically generate an escaped string.

Also I need to allow the user to edit the escaped string and when reading back the current text from the QLineEdit, storing it in a std::string it has to be non-escaped.

Use case.
I want the user to set a termination string (for example \r\n) for a communication object. Passing \r\n to a QLineEdit without any manual escaping, results in two unvisible characters in the QLineEdit input box.

Comment: Explain yourself better.

Comment: okay I wrote a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Do you want the following? https://imgur.com/a/w0rkYve

Comment: yes that is how it should look like. And if I remove the \r from it I should get the unescaped Hello\n back in my std::string

Comment: How do you want to set the text in the `QLineEdit`?, ie the user places it, or with the `setText()` method, also if in the `QLineEdit` it shows `Hello\n` what should you get?

Comment: I need to let the user edit it and I need also to update it using setText().
If it says Hello\n I expect to get Hello followed by the newline character

Comment: could you use: `setText("Hello\\r\\n")`? 
or do you want Qt to convert `Hello\\r\\n` to `Hello\r\n`

Comment: Yes I want Qt to make the conversion back and forth

Comment: Or any "engine" that can make that process automatically so I don't need to manually serach / replace all possible non-printable characters.

Answer (score 1):

"\\r\\n" ? You can create an inline stub the calls qstring::replace and return std with .toStdString

Comment: Mike
Yes but I want to replace any non printable characters like tab and so on. So I want an engine that does the replace automatically without me specifying all possible non printable characters.

Comment: The engine performing this operation does not have to be Qt I suppose, but I don't want to specify and manually handle all non-printable characters manually. What I look for is an "engine" that does the conversion for me.

Comment: Create a string parsing loop with qstring::firstIndexOf ("\\" + 1) and the next character. Or perhaps a regex scheme could be used...

Comment: Regex sounds like an interesting approach

Comment: QregExp has a nice regex API. If you were to abstract a pattern to apply to your strings you could validate them with a single call or loop through validation, returning the int position of where it fails per iteration. This way you could use wildcards for each escape sequence character.